# How to unchecked Return to Stock checkbox of new credit memo in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, creditmemo

I am working on Magento 1.9.2

The problem I am facing is when we create new credit memo there is the list of ordered items in the list where you can tick on the product to make it return to stock or not.

How to uncheck this checkbox by default??

[image]

Comment: Solved:
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/creditmemo/create/items/renderer/default.phtml